# Excel VBA - Delete Single Character from Cell without losing formatting of remainder of cell contents

Tags: string, excel, vba, replace, character

I am trying to delete the first occurrence of "<" and ">" in a cell without losing formatting of the remainder of the cell's contents.

I have looked in several places here, and other, to no avail.

This is what I am trying to do:

Say "A1" contains the text:

```
"This is <a> long string with several <occurrences> of a <special> character."
```

In any case, What I am trying to do is remove the ">", and in a perfect world the "<", from the first word which contains them while maintaining the bold formatting as well as the "<" and ">" on the next word containing them.

This is ONLY other code executing prior to the code I am having issues with.

```
inTx = Range("A2").Value
outTx = Replace(inTx, "Init_Day", Range("A3").Value)
Range("A2").Value = outTx
```

Which replaces the `<placeholder>` text with the actual text, a two digit number in this case.

Here is the code that is not working for me:

```
SearchString = Range("A2").Value
Char1 = "<"
Char2 = ">"
For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
    If Mid(SearchString, i, 1) = Char1 Then
        startPos = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
    If Mid(SearchString, i, 1) = Char2 Then
        endPos = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Range("A2").Characters(startPos, endPos - startPos).Font.Bold = True
Range("A2").Characters(startPos - 1, 1).Delete
```

All code works fine until I reach the last line:

```
Range("A2").Characters(startPos - 1, 1).Delete
```

then nothing happens.

I've even tried:

```
Range("A2").Characters(startPos - 1, 20).Delete
```

Still nothing...

I know this should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Range("A1").Characters(9,1).Delete` works fine for me.  What does the rest of your code look like?  There must be a problem somewhere else.  I'm guessing that line is not even running.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Added the full code snippet in original post to see if it helps to find the problem.

Comment: To explain, because of Excel's constraints on either all bold, or all non-bold text in formula cells, I have developed a work-around where I have added <placeholders> in a cell of text where I can overwrite the <placeholder> with the value output from a formula cell, and bold it, all is working great except for getting rid of the actual <> characters.

Comment: how about doing a find/replace on the whole sheet?

Comment: @nutsch: That would lose the in-cell formatting.

Comment: @nutsch, what mwolfe02 said...  That is what I tried first, well on the cell itself, not the whole sheet, but I need to keep the formatting... Errg..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
Sub Foo()
    Const Char1 As String = "<", Char2 As String = ">"
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim i As Integer, startPos As Integer, endPos As Integer
    SearchString = Range("A2").Value
    startPos = InStr(SearchString, Char1)
    endPos = InStr(SearchString, Char2)
    Range("A2").Characters(startPos, endPos - startPos).Font.Bold = True
    Range("A2").Characters(startPos, 1).Delete
    Range("A2").Characters(endPos - 1, 1).Delete
End Sub
```

Turns this:

`Some <bold> text I just <made> up.`

Into this:

```
Some bold text I just <made> up.
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Odd.  I would try sprinkling some `Debug.Print` statements around or setting a couple of breakpoints to see if you can figure out what is going on.  It seems that there is some issue buried further down in your code...perhaps there are non-printable characters being inserted in A2; or you have an `On Error Resume Next` directive that is silently swallowing some bug; or any number of other things.

Comment: Note, you should be able to copy and paste the text `Some <bold> text I just <made> up.` into cell A2 of a blank workbook, copy my `Foo()` sub, and verify that it is working for you.  If that works, then you'll know your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Ill try it out... On a new sheet, new sub, new everything and see what happens.

Comment: Well what the frick... It works..  Only other thing I am doing before the code posted is copying the value produced from a formula into the cell.  i will add that portion and maybe you can see whats wrong... Sorry for not adding it to begin with but I "thought" it was working as planned.

Comment: @XCHANGE: I'm closing up shop for the night.  I'll have a look in the morning if you and others here haven't sorted it out by then.  Best of luck.

Comment: It turns out that the cell contained too many characters, 500+.  I had not thought about items failing because of this.  In any case, I will mark your answer as the solution since it narrowed down my code a bit.  Thanks!