# Removing Trail Commas without removing color format

Tags: vba, trim

I found this vba that trims the trailing commas, but it changes my color format.

Is it possible to retain the color format?

**Current Code**

```vb
Function removetrailcomma(txt As String) As String
    If Right(txt, 1) = " " Or Right(txt, 1) = "," Then
        removetrailcomma = removetrailcomma(Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1))
    Else
        removetrailcomma = txt
    End If
End Function
```

Current Cell - Peter(In black font), 1st Rank(In red font),
Current Code result - Peter(In black font), 1st Rank(In black font)
Desired result - Peter(In black font), 1st Rank(In red font)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're having is that you're trying to edit the cell by taking the text out, changing the text, and then putting the text back in. The text that you're working with does not have inherent formatting as a string. The colour of the text is a property of the range (see the [Font.Color property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.color) for details). So when you put the string back into the cell, you're erasing the cell formatting.

To change the text in the cell without eliminating formatting, it's easier to work with the Range object of the cell itself. Here's a function that would do what you want:

```
Sub CleanupCell(InputCell As Range)
    Dim DataLen As String, DeleteChar As String
    
    'Take in last character in cell
    DeleteChar = Right(InputCell.Value, 1)
    
    'Delete the last character in the cell if a comma or space
    If (DeleteChar = "," Or DeleteChar = " ") Then
        DataLen = Len(InputCell.Value)
        InputCell.Characters(DataLen, 1).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

This function doesn't eliminate formatting because it doesn't overwrite the text in the cell, just deletes a single character from the end of the cell. I based this off an [older Sx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150231/excel-vba-delete-single-character-from-cell-without-losing-formatting-of-remai).

Comment: Thanks!... but I am not able to run this code... I added this in a module it didn't run and I tried adding it in the sheet... but somehow this doesn't show me when I click on view macros... I am not sure where I am going wrong... could you please let me know?

Comment: I also tried adding this as a Function... but the result it gives me is 0..... I think I am making a silly error... but cant find out... please help!

Comment: The only macros that will show up are the subroutines that do not take input variables. So VBA wouldn't be able to run the above code on its own because it wouldn't know what value to assign InputCell but you could,e.g. have a subroutine without inputs that calls the subroutine CleanupCell with a specific input., e.g.:

`Sub Test()` containing `    Call CleanupCell(Range("M23"))`

If you want to have this subroutine available for any random cell without having to hard-code a range input, you could remove the InputCell input and instead have a local Range variable that selects a cell.

Comment: An example of a local Range variable selecting a cell would be, for instance, using ActiveCell to specify the cell that you've currently clicked. So you could rewrite the code to use something like:
`Dim InputCell As Range`
`Set InputCell = Application.ActiveWindow.ActiveCell`
This would tell the subroutine to apply the code to whatever cell you've clicked on. You could then delete the input variable so that the top line is `Sub CleanupCell()` and you'd be able to call the sub from Macros.

Comment: Making this code a function will return 0 because there is no output value assigned to CleanupCell. A subroutine carries out actions without returning a specific "result" value, unlike a function. In your code, returning a result value is not helpful because you don't want to pull the text out of the cell and into your code as a variable. Doing so would clear the formatting of the text, so if you were to pull the text into the code and return it as a function value, then put that in the cell, it would clear formatting. Performing actions on the cell directly will preserve formatting.